# selenium webdriver accepting Alert fired from inside an iframe with IEDriver won't work. Any work arounds?

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, selenium

I've got an application with several iframes.   Webdriver handles the Alerts fine when they are fired in the root context but doesn't see to find alerts that are fired from inside an iFrame.  Well it works with firefox but doesn't work with IE.

I've tried several different tactics to work around it but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

can you make sure whether you have selected the corresponding iFrame before trying to handle alert pop up ?

Comment: Did that.... the code runs fine in the firefox webdriver.  Unfortunately the application uses lots of nested iframes and javascsript popup windows both things I abhor.